# Creating a parquet file on AWS Lambda function

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, parquet

I'm receiving a set of (1 Mb) CSV/JSON files on S3 that I would like to convert to Parquet. I was expecting to be able of converting this files easily to Parquet using a Lambda function.

After looking on Google I didn't found a solution to this without have some sort of Hadoop.

Since this is a file conversion, I can't believe there is not an easy solution for this. Someone has some Java/Scala sample code to do this conversion?

Comment: As Parquet is not in a textual, human-readable format, I can understand why that doesn't work. Theoretically, you can use AWS EMR and Spark for that, but I have the same goal and I am having problems with the schema, because all the rows/files may not have all the values available in all columns and then Spark may read them in different types. And then writing to Parquet would write in different schemas and afterwards you could not read in multiple Parquet files together because their schemas do not match.

Comment: I can understand the fact that it is a Binary file format, but does it needs to depend on Hadoop?
At the end we changed our requirements and the Parket is no longer needed (due to unrelated reasons). We could have gone with some standalone spark app for example (JAR of 100MB, passing the normal 50 MB AWS limit).

Comment: Oh okay. What did you use instead?

Comment: For now we use GZip JSON. When we define the final tool, we will decide the final format. There will be Batch Service, EC2 machines, EMR, ...

Comment: I am using EMR, but with raw JSON, Spark read in ~330gb of data (4x c3.2xlarge instances) in about 17 mins and wrote it to Parquet in about 69 mins. Then reading this parquet took only a second. Probably because it didn't need to infer the schema anymore. Of course additional operations would take more time, but still Parquet seems the best option for me.

Answer (score 4):

If your input JSON files are not large (< 64 MB, beyond which lambda is likely to hit memory caps) and either have simple data types or you are willing to flatten the structs, you might consider using [pyarrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/), even though the route is slightly convoluted.

It involved using [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
df = pd.read_json(file.json)
```

followed by converting it into parquet file:

```
pq = pa.parquet.write_table(df, file.pq)
```

Above example does auto-inference of data-types. You can override it by using the argument `dtype` while loading JSON. It's only major shortcoming is that pyarrow only supports `string, bool, float, int, date, time, decimal, list, array`.

**Update (a more generic solution)**:

Consider using [json2parquet](https://github.com/andrewgross/json2parquet).

However, if the input data has nested dictionaries, it first needs to be flattened, i.e. convert:

```
{a: {b: {c: d}}} to {a.b.c: d}
```

Then, this data needs to be ingested as pyarrow batch with json2parquet:

```
pa_batch = j2p.ingest_data(data)
```

and now the batch can be loaded as PyArrow dataframe:

```
df = pa.Table.from_batches([pa_batch])
```

and output in parquet file:

```
pq = pa.parquet.write_table(df, file.pq)
```

Comment: Do you have any tips for packaging? I can't seem to get pandas and pyarrow under the 250MB repo size limit amazon imposes =/